# asp.net mvc2 dropdownlistfor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to create a dropdownlist in my asp.net MVC2 view and I am following code:

```
 foreach (var whiteout in Model)
        {
%>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= whiteout.Field.NiceName%>
       <%  Html.DropDownListFor("anyname", Model); %>

<%
                }
            }
%>
```

but I am getting error that second parameter is not correct. Second parameter is a list. Here is how Model is declared at the top of partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<EnviroTracker.Entities.Whiteout>>" %>
```

Please suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DropDownListFor` helper takes a `SelectList` as second argument and a lambda expression to a simple property as first:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SomeProperty, 
    new SelectList(Model.SomeList, "ValueProperty", "TextProperty")
) %>
```

If you want to use the weakly typed `DropDownList` helper you could manually specify the name of the property it will be bound to but the second argument should still be a `SelectList`:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "SomeProperty", 
    new SelectList(Model.SomeList, "ValueProperty", "TextProperty")
) %>
```

Comment: @Darin: I don't have x => x.SomeProperty instead it shows x.list functions /collection functions because my model is a collection

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, well you should then modify the view model type for this partial if you want to use the strongly typed `DropDownListFor` helper which is what I would recommend. So you would introduce another view model which will have two properties: a scalar property to bind to and a collection property containing the values of the dropdown list which will be an enumerable. Then you will strongly type your view to this new view model.

Comment: @Darin: I used this: <%= Html.DropDownList("SomeProperty", new SelectList(Model, "FieldID", whiteout.Field.NiceName)
) %> and I am getting DataBinding: 'EnviroTracker.Entities.Whiteout' does not contain a property with the name 'Temperature '.

Comment: @Darin: I cant make viewmodel because I am calling partial view like this:  Html.RenderPartial("WhiteoutList",Model.Whiteouts); and not from controller.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, well, the error message seems pretty self explanatory. As far as the view model is concerned of course that you can make one. You just need to modify the `Whiteouts` property of your main view model. It should no longer be a collection but it should be the new view model I suggested you.

Comment: @Darin: How can I get rid of this error. NiceName is not in whiteout rather it is in field entity which is connected to whiteout entity through navigation property